# How to check if user clicked on an image in web browser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I noticed in the events of the web browser control there is nothing like a click event. So how do I check if the user clicked on an image in the web browser control?

// seudo

```
void webbroseer_click() {
if type == image {
do this
}
}
```

Comment: Oops, I flagged as a dup a question I then realized was for WPF, not winforms. Sorry about that. Though it is possible that they are similar (I haven't looked at it closely, and don't know that much about WPF.) (I really wish they'd add that long-requested "cancel a flag" feature. :()

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the active element's tag name is an image, and then run your specific code.

```
void WebBrowser1_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
     if (WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.TagName == "IMG")
     {
          //Do Something
     }
}
```

Comment: right but the problem is theres no web browser click function

Comment: You need to create it, for example, `WebBrowser. Click += WebBrowser_Click`